# Ubuntu SELinux - why different types for files var_t vs file_t

Tags: selinux, html

I have Ubuntu 14.04 running on two vm's.  I have have permissive SELinux enabled on both.  On system1, all of my files + linked directories in `/var/www/html` are marked as `var_t` and the symbolic linked directory (to `home/../Documents`) is RED and appears not to work.  On system2, all of my files + linked directories in `/var/www/html` are marked as `file_t` and the symbolic linked directory (to `home/../chipweb`) is NOT RED and is ok to use?

Why are my file SELinux types different in these two identical directories?  I am confused?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The files were probably created in different way on both systems so this is the reason for different types.

To make sure it is in "system-default" state, you can relabel the filesystem (or at least the required directories) using `restorecon(8)`.

Answer (score 0):

I did run restorecon and it put everything back to var_t type, but, I am still confused as to why all of my html files in /var/www/html were file_t type?

two last questions:

1. where is the permissive log located?
2. does SELinux block symbolic links to file_t files and directories when everything in /var/www/html is supposed to be type file_t?

thanks for the help!

Comment: 1) I'm not sure what do you mean by permissive log, but selinux denials are logged in audit log -- /var/log/audit/audit.log on CentOS/RHEL/Fedora, but I recommend to read it through ausearch tool.

2) SELinux doesn't block links ... it can block creation of links if they are created by somehow limited process/user, otherwise I don't see reason why it should do so.

Comment: Where are selinux denials logged in Ubuntu SELinux?

Comment: Thanks - I installed auditd.  I notice that I get a permission denied trying to access the directory, so, I am assuming we need other tools to review the log.  Also, in regards to my question #2 above: I thought the TYPE _t of a file determined what app/process type could access that file.  So, that is why I thought apache (which handles var_t types of files, might not be able to access home/document: file_t types of files - within SELinux.